# Compositum of normal extensions and embedding

Tags: extension-field

I want to show "If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are normal extensions of $F$, then the compositum $E_1 E_2$ and $E_1\cap E_2$ are normal extensions."

I already prove this, but I find another proof using an embedding $\sigma$ on $\overline{F}$(not F-embedding).

It says $\sigma (E_1 E_2)=\sigma (E_1) \sigma (E_2)$. I think it holds because $\sigma$ is an embedding, but it is hard to prove it. Do I need to use normalities of $E_i$?

Moreover, more generally, for embedding $\sigma$ on $\overline{F}$,  $ \sigma(F(S))=\sigma(F)(\sigma(S))$?

(I know it is holds for $\sigma(E_1\cap E_2)$..)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

> Do I need to use normalities of $E_i$?

Yes.

> for embedding $\sigma$ on $\overline{F}$,  $ \sigma(F(S))=\sigma(F)(\sigma(S))$?

I suppose here $S\subseteq \overline{F}$ is a set of generators for the extension $F\leq F(S)=:E$ and $\sigma:E\hookrightarrow\overline{F}$ is an embedding of $E$ into the algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$. However I believe the correct generalization should address how embeddings and compositums interact. See the proof below.

> (I know it is holds for $\sigma(E_1\cap E_2)$...)

If you mean that whenever $\sigma$ is an embedding we have $\sigma(E_1\cap E_2)=\sigma(E_1)\cap\sigma(E_1)$, then this is an elementary set theoretical fact and you don't need any field structure to show this (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138286/fa-cap-b-fa-cap-fb-iff-f-is-injective)). In the case of compositums though, you do need the field structure.

---

I believe you are citing Lang's *Algebra*, 3e (Theorem V.3.4 on p. 238), the relevant part of which is as follows:

**Theorem:** Let $k$ be a field, $k\leq\begin{smallmatrix} E_1\\E_2\end{smallmatrix}\leq K$, and $E_1,E_2$ be normal over $k$. Then $E_1E_2$ is normal over $k$.

**Proof:** Let $\sigma: E_1E_2\hookrightarrow \overline{k}:\sigma\vert_k\equiv \operatorname{id}_k$. Then we have $\sigma_1:=\sigma\vert_{E_1}: E_1\hookrightarrow \overline{k}$ and $\sigma_2:=\sigma\vert_{E_2}: E_2\hookrightarrow \overline{k}$ (both over $k$). Since $E_1$ and $E_2$ are normal over $k$, $\sigma_1\in\operatorname{Aut}(K_1)$ and $\sigma_2\in\operatorname{Aut}(K_2)$, so that $\sigma_1(E_1)=E_1,\sigma_2(E_2)=E_2$.

$E_1,E_2\leq E_1E_2 \implies \sigma_1(E_1),\sigma_2(E_2)\leq \sigma(E_1E_2)$. Since $\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)$ is by definition the smallest field (contained in some larger field that contains both $\sigma_1(E_1)$ and $\sigma_2(E_2)$) that contains both $\sigma_1(E_1)$ and $\sigma_2(E_2)$, $E_1E_2=\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)\leq\sigma(E_1E_2)$. We have

\begin{align}
[E_1E_2:k]&=[\sigma(E_1E_2):\sigma(k)]\\
&=[\sigma(E_1E_2):\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)][\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2):\sigma(k)]\\
&=[\sigma(E_1E_2):\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)][E_1E_2:k]\\
& \implies [\sigma(E_1E_2):\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)]=1\\
& \implies E_1E_2=\sigma_1(E_1)\sigma_2(E_2)=\sigma(E_1E_2),
\end{align}

where the first equality holds since $\sigma$ in an embedding. Thus $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(E_1E_2)$, so that $E_1E_2$ is normal over $k$.

---

To put the above theorem (in its complete form) in perspective here are some further details:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the class of all fields. $\mathcal{F}$ is partially ordered by inclusion (or extension) $\leq$:

$$k\leq F \iff k\subseteq F \mbox{ and } k \mbox{ is a subfield of } F.$$

A class of extensions $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\leq$ is **distinguished** if it is

1. **filterable**: $k\leq F\leq E,k\leq_{\mathcal{C}}E \implies k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} F\leq_{\mathcal{C}} E$,
2. **transitive**: $k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} F\leq_{\mathcal{C}} E\implies k\leq_{\mathcal{C}}E$,
3. **closed under liftings**: $k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} E\leq K,k\leq F\leq K \implies F\leq_{\mathcal{C}} EF$.

Observe that a distinguished $\mathcal{C}$ is also closed under compositums:

4. **closed under compositums**: $k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} E\leq K,k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} F\leq K \implies k\leq_{\mathcal{C}} EF$.

Examples of distinguished classes of field extensions include

- finite extensions,
- finitely generated extensions,
- algebraic extensions.

The class $\mathcal{N}$ of normal extensions  on the other hand is not distinguished:

**Example 1:** If $\beta\in\Bbb{R}: X^3-2\in\ker(\operatorname{ev}_\beta),$ and $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity (i.e. $\omega^3=1, \omega\neq1$), then $\Bbb{Q}\leq_\mathcal{N}\Bbb{Q}(\beta,\omega)$ and $\Bbb{Q}\leq\Bbb{Q}(\beta)\leq\Bbb{Q}(\beta,\omega)$ but $\Bbb{Q}\not\leq_{\mathcal{N}}\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$, so that filterability is not satisfied.

**Example 2:** If $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}:X^4-2\in\ker(\operatorname{ev}_\alpha)$, then $\Bbb{Q}\leq_{\mathcal{N}}\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^2)\leq_\mathcal{N}\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ but $\Bbb{Q}\not\leq_\mathcal{N}\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ so that transitivity is not satisfied.

Even though $\mathcal{N}$ is not filterable nor transitive, hence not distinguished, it is not completely undistinguished, so to speak:

**Theorem V.3.4:** $\mathcal{N}$ is

$ \quad$1'. **half-filterable**: $k\leq F\leq E,k\leq_{\mathcal{N}}E \implies F\leq_{\mathcal{N}} E$,

3. closed under liftings,
4. closed under compositums.