# The change of variables theorem from Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, change-of-variable, borel-measures

In Rudin's Real and Complex analysis, there is the change-of-variables theorem, which is Thm 7.26.

There are some conditions. I will write some of them relating to my question:

> (i) $X \subset V \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $V$ is open, $T: V \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is continuous.
>
> (ii) $X$ is Lebesgue measurable, $T$ is one-to-one on $X$, and $T$ is differentiable at every point of $X$
>
> Also,  $Y = T(X)$ and $E = T^{-1}(A) = \{x \in V: T(x) \in A\}$. Here, $A$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Then, why is $T(E \cap X) = A \cap Y$. Isn't it $T(E \cap X) \subset A \cap Y$? If $T(E \cap X)$ are to be equal to $A \cap Y$, shouldn't $T$ be one-to-one on **$V$**, not $X$? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&y\in T(E\cap X) \\
\iff &\exists x\in E\cap X : y = T(x) \\
\iff &y\in T(E)\cap T(X) \\
\iff &y\in T(T^{-1}(A)) \cap Y \\
\iff &y\in A\cap Y
\end{align*}

---

**Correction**

I simply thought that $T$ is one-to-one on $X$ and $m(T(V-X)) = 0$ implies $T$ is one-to-one on $V$ and $T(E\cap X) = T(E)\cap T(X)$.
However, I could check that it is wrong from [$f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ $\iff$ $f$ is injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138286/fa-cap-b-fa-cap-fb-iff-f-is-injective) and [Is a continuous function one-to-one if it is one-to-one almost everywhere on its range?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532485/is-a-continuous-function-one-to-one-if-it-is-one-to-one-almost-everywhere-on-its).
Maybe I believed in Rudin too much.
Nevertheless, Theorem 7.26 holds as it is.
To see this, observe that actually $m(T(E\cap X)) = m(A\cap Y)$ is used in (10).
We can check $m(T(E\cap X)) = m(A\cap Y)$ from $T(E\cap X) \subset T(E)\cap T(X)$, $m(T(E-X)) \le m(T(V-X)) = 0$, and
\begin{equation*}
m(A\cap Y) = m(T(E)\cap T(X)) \le m(T(E)) \le m(T(E\cap X)) + m(T(E-X)) = m(T(E\cap X)).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks, but $T(T^{-1}(A)) = A$ doesn't hold generally.

Comment: @withgrace1040 $T(T^{-1}(A))\cap Y = \{T(x)\in A: x\in X\}\cap Y = \{T(x)\in A\cap Y:x\in X\} = A\cap Y$ because $Y = T(X)$.

Comment: Yes, your argument for that is true. However, the second $\Longleftrightarrow$ doesn't hold. More specifically, $T(E \cap X) \subset T(E) \cap T(X)$. They are not necessarily equal.